# How to implement Scikit GridSerachCV with fit_generator in keras

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I want to perform a hyperparameter sweep using scikit-wrapper GirdSearchCV on this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/rodrigo2019/keras-yolo2).

For which I am trying to run GridSearchCV on using the scikit-wrapper:

```
from sklearn.model_Selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.wrappers.sckit_learn import KerasClassifier

#After the compile in frontend.py
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn = TinyYoloFeature, verbose = 0) #TinyYoloFeature is in backend.py

#After the above command in frontend.py
batch_size = [16,32,64]
learning rate = [0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001]
param_grid = dict (epcohs = nb_epochs,
                   batch_size = batch_size)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid = param_grid,n_jobs=-1)
grid_result = grid.fit() #How to go about ????

#print result
print ("Best: %f using %s using %
(grid_result.best_score_,grid_result.best_params_,)
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']  
for mean, stdev, param in zip (means, stds, params):
print("%f (%f) with: %r" %(mean, stdev, param))
```

But the code uses a fit_genrator. All the support online is with respect to model.fit.Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854232/keras-scikit-learn-using-fit-generator-with-cross-validation